# MySQL Indexes in Doctrine / Zend Framework 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have some serious Performance Problems and i found out that it is because the lack of Indexes in MySQL. So i added an Index to the Table Definition of the Entity:

```
@ORM\Table(
    name="test",
    indexes={
        @ORM\Index(name="test_idx", columns={"testfield"})
    }
)
```

These lines are ok (hopefully) but resulting in simply nothing, When i run *doctrine orm:validate-schema* it says, that the Database is in Sync. When i add the Index manually to MySQL it says it is no longer in sync, and wants to drop the index. I am a little bit confused because the CLI-Tool does not add the Index (but drops it, if it exists), and i am not getting any error message? What ist wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work this way, though, the Index-Support ist broken at the moment. Have a look at:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/368